# Autoclustering does not work on AWS with RabbitMQ

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rabbitmq

We are using the latest version of RabbitMQ, v3.7.2 on a few EC2 instances on AWS. We want to use [auto clustering](https://www.rabbitmq.com/cluster-formation.html) which comes default in the product, Cluster Formation and Peer Discovery.

After we start RabbitMQ it fails/ignores to do this. The only message we see in the log file is:

```
[info] <0.229.0> Peer discovery backend rabbit_peer_discovery_aws does not support registration, skipping registration.
```

On our RabbitMQ EC2 instance an IAM role is attached with the coorect policy. The rabbitMQ config is:

```
cluster_formation.peer_discovery_backend = rabbit_peer_discovery_aws
cluster_formation.aws.region = eu-west-1
cluster_formation.aws.use_autoscaling_group = true
cluster_formation.aws.use_private_ip = true
```

Did anyone face this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your rabbitmq.conf and restart rabbitmq-server

```
log.file.level = debug
```

It allows you to see a discovery request to AWS in logs.

Then do this on any rabbitmq node:

```
rabbitmqctl stop_app
rabbitmqctl reset
rabbitmqctl start_app
```

It'll execute the discovery again. Check rabbitmq logs for 'AWS Request' you'll see corresponding response so that you can check if your ec2 instances were found by specified tags. If no, something is wrong with your tags.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer (not enough reputation points to comment) but I'm dealing with the same thing. I've double-checked that the security groups are correct, they allow ports 4369, 5672 and 15672 (confirmed via telnet/netcat), and the IAM policies are correct. Debug logging shows nothing else. I'm at a loss how to figure this one out.

Comment: Just for anyone finding this - even though rabbit uses well-known port e.g. 15672, 25672 .... I believe after negotiation on that port it my switch to another i.e. your SG should allow all from self